# SQL Server 10.50 OVER PARTITION not recognized

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, window-functions

I am trying to use `OVER PARTITION` in SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.1600.1), but writing and executing it indicates an error near the ORDER, I tried to run this same query without modifications in SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.4100.1), but it works without problems, and in the SQL Server documentation I have not managed to find anything, I know there are other ways to simulate this process, but I would like to know if there is a more agile equivalence. Thank you

```
SELECT 
    e.ID, e.[date], 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.[date] DESC) AS ind
FROM 
    events e 
JOIN 
    Manager h ON h.ID = e.ID AND h.Active = 1 AND h.[Status] <> 30037 
WHERE 
    e.Iary IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY 
    e.ID, e.[date]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Comment: These window functions were introduced in SQL Server **2012** (v11.x) and are **not available** in SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50). And by the way, just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: El COUNT(*) es para llevar una cuenta prograsiva de ese grupo, pero ya lo solucione, en 10.50 no es compatible usar el ORDER BY con un COUNT(*),  cosa que si funciona y cumple el objetivo en 12.0, cambiando el COUNT(*) por ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The COUNT () is to keep a program account of that group, but already solve it, in 10.50 it is not compatible to use the ORDER BY with a COUNT (), which if it works and meets the objective in 12.0, changing the COUNT (* ) by ROW_NUMBER ()

`SELECT 
    e.ID, e.[date], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.[date] DESC) AS ind
FROM 
    events e 
JOIN 
    Manager h ON h.ID = e.ID AND h.Active = 1 AND h.[Status] <> 30037 
WHERE 
    e.Iary IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY 
    e.ID, e.[date]`

Comment: SO is an English only website.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language and when replying copy the untranslated text

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ORDER BY e.[date] DESC`

```
SELECT e.ID, e.[date], COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY e.ID) AS ind
FROM events e 
JOIN Manager h ON h.ID = e.ID AND h.Active = 1 AND h.[Status] <> 30037 
WHERE e.Iary IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY e.ID, e.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

your query should look like this. you only want to get the `count()` per `e.ID`

```
SELECT e.ID, e.[date], COUNT(*) AS ind
        FROM events e 
        JOIN Manager h ON h.ID = e.ID AND h.Active = 1 AND h.[Status] <> 30037 
        WHERE e.Iary IN (1,2,3) 
        GROUP BY e.ID, e.[date]
        ORDER BY e.[date]
```